# Hightcharts: reset the graph

Tags: javascript, jquery, r, highcharts

I am building Highcharts within R by using rCharts library. But I think anyone who is familiar with Javascript or Highcharts could answer my question as well. I incorporated a function to allow user to ctrl+click to select a specific series.

Please see this for your reference: https://jsfiddle.net/derekrezek/Nkeep/109/

```
a$plotOptions(
  series = list( 
    events = list(
      legendItemClick = "#! function(e) {
        var hideAllOthers = e.browserEvent.metaKey|| e.browserEvent.ctrlKey;
        if (hideAllOthers) {
            var seriesIndex = this.index;
            var series = this.chart.series;
        for (var i = 0; i < series.length; i++) {
        if (series[i].index === seriesIndex) {
        if (!series[i].visible) series[i].setVisible(true, false);
        } else {
        if (series[i].visible) series[i].setVisible(false, false);
        }
        }
        this.chart.redraw();
        return false;
        }} !#")
  )
)
```

It doesn't impact original functionality of Highcharts and allow user to select a specific series by ctrl+click the legend item. However, what if I have 50+ legends. After I select one specific series and then I want the all other series back, I will have to click all of invisible series to show them again, which is not practical.

Anyone knows how to make a reset button? or allow user to ctrl+click again to restore the original graph?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer to this [example](https://jsfiddle.net/wiltsc/Nkeep/130/), I have added a Reset button to `destroy` and re-instantiate the Line chart with default value.